# Where is the base domain stored in database D7

Tags: uri, database

Is there an equivalent row to the Wordpress "Home" and "Site"? In otherwords, where can I look in the database to figure out what the domain the site is on?
 I'm using mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be one or more of the following:

```
<?php
print $GLOBALS['base_url'];    // Set by drupal_settings_initialize() or settings.php.
print $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];   // Set by apache.
print $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; // Set by apache.
```

You can also check the database with this query

```
SELECT * FROM variable WHERE value LIKE '%example.com%'
```

where example.com is the domain; this is not guaranteed to be correct though.

Comment: Interesting. I think the php commands will probably get me what I need. To clarify, the problem I'm trying to solve is that I have numerous Drupal sites set up on the server. I know that the directories that they live in are not correlative to the domains the sites are at. So, I'm trying to figure out how to determine if the sites are live from files and database. (most of the time our default set up doesn't include base_url in the settings file, *sad*

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for $base_url in `/sites/default/settings.php`.  As far as I know everything in the database works off this value, and it is not explicitly set in the DB

Answer (score 3):

There really isn't a perfect analog to `wp_options.siteurl` & `wp_options.home` in Drupal. The closest thing is `variable.site_frontpage` for home path & `$base_url` in **settings.php** that contains the site domain URL root.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily evaluated from the code in `drupal_settings_initialize()` in file `includes/bootstrap.inc`

As seen in the code below, Drupal first tries to get it from `$base_url`, if not set then Drupal reads it from `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

```
function drupal_settings_initialize() {

    if (isset($base_url)) {
        // Parse fixed base URL from settings.php.
        $parts = parse_url($base_url);
        ...
    }
    else {
        // Create base URL.
        $http_protocol = $is_https ? 'https' : 'http';
        $base_root = $http_protocol . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        ...
    }
```

WARNING: Since `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` could be easily spoofed using an http request header "`Host: something.com`", this means you should, I repeat, you should assign a value to `$base_url` in the `settings.php` file to avoid the }else{ condition above.